# d3 bootstrap, responsively centering svg

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 svg that I want to stay centered. I've tried making a class:

```
.tocenter {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However this is not working. I've also tried wrapping the `svg` in some `divs` but I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

the svg that contains the svg graph (which resizes based on the window):
`<svg id="graph" class="img-responsive tocenter"></svg>`

code:

```
<svg id="graph" class="img-responsive tocenter"></svg>
<h4 class="text-center">Siblings in College</h4>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData(0)>No Siblings in College</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData(1)>1+ Sibling(s) in College</button>
</div>
<div><br /></div>
<h4 class="text-center">Household Income</h4>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(1)><$30k</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(2)>$30k-$48k</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(3)>$48k-$75k</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(4)>$75k-$110k</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(5)>$110k-$150k</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(6)>>$150k</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you edit the question and include the HTML of the svg tag and its surrounding elements.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Because of `img-responsive`.

Comment: @As3adTintin -  i have made an edit to my answer. Looks perfectly center to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I made [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgsLo1fd/)** that may help fix your issue.  Notice I specified the width of the svg element so that the parent container can properly add the text align property to the SVG.

**The HTML & CSS:**

```
<div>
  <svg> </svg >
</div>

svg {
  width: *some value*
}

div {
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: hmm, it centers but not the same center as `text-center` gave the bootstrap divs

Comment: I got it to work using `.yutest {
    padding-left: 12%;
    text-align: left;
    /*border: solid 1px black;*/
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `center-block` helper class to center your svg.

[**center-block**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)

> Set an element to display: block and center via margin. Available as a mixin and class.

Also make sure to add the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes to your svg element.

```js
var margin        = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}, 
    w             = 1024 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h             = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    circleRadii   = 15,
    triData       = [{x: 120, y: 30}, {x: 250, y: 120}, {x: 340, y: 160}],
    circleData    = [{x: 110, y: 10}, {x: 140, y: 80}, {x: 460, y: 70}];

var svg = d3.select("#graph")
.attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", h + margin.left + margin.right)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tri =  svg.selectAll(".point")
.data(triData)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "point")
.attr("stroke", "none")
.attr("fill", "rgba(30,110,160,.5)")
.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(1024*2))
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(circleData)
.enter()
.append("circle");

var circleAttr = circles
.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
.attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
.attr("r", circleRadii)
.style("fill", "rgba(10,100,0,.5)");
```

```css
svg {
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <svg id="graph" class="img-responsive center-block" width="1024" height="300" viewBox="0 0 1024 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"></svg>
      <h4 class="text-center">Siblings in College</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData(0)>No Siblings in College</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData(1)>1+ Sibling(s) in College</button>
    </div>
    <div><br /></div>
    <h4 class="text-center">Household Income</h4>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(1)><$30k</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(2)>$30k-$48k</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(3)>$48k-$75k</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(4)>$75k-$110k</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(5)>$110k-$150k</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick=updateData2(6)>>$150k</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.It is almost what I am hoping to achieve. It centered the svg when I wasn't using responsive widths, however I would like my graph to be responsive so it can fit on different screens. When I use your code with the responsive svg, the svg moves slightly but seems more left justified. 

`var margin = 40,`
    `width = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("width")) - margin*2,`
    `height = parseInt(d3.select("#graph").style("height")) - margin*2;`

Comment: Just saw that the `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` attributes are missing on your svg. Works just fine with `img-responsive` class.